# Stop sshd after client disconnects

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

Is it possible to run some command (as root/the sshd user) when a client disconnects?

Or some other method of killing sshd after a single connection terminates?

Comment: you can add a cronjob task to run every second (or minute) to check if there is an active ssh connection, and if not just kill the service

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: @k.Cyborg Sure, but the connection may not exist for some time in the first place, so would also have to be started only when the connection opens..

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's exactly why I said 'or some other method of [X]'. I want sshd to admit a single session, then quit afterwards.

Comment: And I suspect you want this for a reason. What is the reason then? `sshd -d` does what you want, but it's not designed for regular use.

Comment: I would echo what Kamil said, but I think he was referring to -D rather than -d.  If you can provide some detail as to what you're trying to accomplish, we might can be more helpful.  Killing sshd after a single connection might have it's place, but there may be better ways to tackle the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @mikem I meant exactly `sshd -d`, the debug mode where the tool processes exactly one connection and then exits.

Comment: @Kamil Yes, -d would work, but -D does the same thing without all of the noisy debug data.  From what I gathered from the OP, it didn't seem like he was looking to debug a connection as much as just to terminate after the session ended.  Either one would work.

Comment: @mikem In my tests `sshd -D` processes many connections (consecutive, simultaneous, it doesn't matter) just fine, it does not exit. This is exactly what I expected after reading the [documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#D). `sshd -d` actually exits after processing the first connection (which counts even if it fails to authenticate, even if it doesn't "speak" SSH).

Comment: @Kamil You are correct.  Sorry for the confusion, I could have swore I used -D a while back for this exact purpose.  Apparently not.

Comment: @OJFord Maybe monitor `/var/log/auth.log` ("Session <number> logged out") or via `systemctl status systemd-logind.service --no-pager`

Answer (score 0):

Check [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586161/execute-script-on-ssh-exit) out

Or you can:-

```bash
alias exit="killall sshd ; exit"
```